# Proof a function continuous at a point through the condition of its first derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis

There was a Corollary stated that: if all the first partial derivatives of $f$ exists and are continuous in an open set $D$, then $f$ itself is continuous in $D$.

However, consider a function $f:R^2\rightarrow R$.

Assume Condition $(1)$: $f$ was known to be continuous at everywhere except at point $p=(p_1,p_2)$; also known its partial derivative $f_x,f_y$ exists everywhere expect at point $p$. (That is, known $f_x, f_y$ exists everywhere, but did not know if $f_x,f_y$ exists at $p$.)

Condition $(2)$ that: $f_x(p)=f_y(p)$

Condition $(3)$: Treat $f_x$ as a single variable function with $y=p_2$, that is function $g:R\rightarrow R$ such that $g(x)=f_x(x,p_2)$ is continuous (or in the other words, $f_x$ continuous on the $y$ axis); similar $f_x(p_1,y)$ is continuous; $f_y(p_1,y)$ is continuous; and $f_y(x,p_2)$ is also continuous.

If only given Condition $(1)$ and Condition $(2)$. It could not imply that $f$ was continuous at $p$.

Question 1:
If given condition $(1)$, $(2)$and $(3)$ together. Can they imply $f$ was continuous at $p$? How to proof it?

Question 2:
Can condition $(2)$ and $(3)$ imply $f$ continuous at $p$?

Question 3:
Can condition $(3)$ itself imply $f$ continuous at $p$?

Comment: In condition 1 you state $f_x,f_y$ exist everywhere except at point $p$. Then in condition 2 you write $f_x(p)=f_y(p)$, which assumes the existence of $f_x,f_y$ at the point $p$. For this reason, as written, condition 1 and 2 will never occur at the same time

Comment: Sorry, it was known $f_x, f_y$ exists everywhere, but did not known if $f_x,f_y$ exists at $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2)$ when $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0.$ Then $f$ satisfies conditions (1),(2), and (3) but $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0).$

Comment: It's not possible to pick any value other than $0$ at $(0,0)$ with condition $(3)$ that was given.

Comment: It's still not continuous at (0,0). This is an old textbook example.

Comment: Regarding $f(0,0)$ I'd rather be redundant than wrong